# Boost::geometry is it how to turn MultiPoint into Poligon with holes?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-geometry

So We have a set of points. like this:

[image]

We want to get united polygon with holes (calculated as if each point was square or circle with some radius and that polygon would be union of such points):

[image]

(shown in green)

As you see it is neither [Convex hull](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull) nor [Concave Hull](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/1200/concave-hull-definition-algorithms-and-practical-solutions). It's just the area under the points with a given area at each point.

Is it possible to do such a thing with boost geometry and, if so, how?